# Node.js function to generate RSA keys using Open SSL

Tags: node.js, openssl, rsa

I'm using Node.js as a server side language and I would like to generate an RSA key pairs for any user that registers himself on my website. I'm using a module called [keypair](https://npmjs.org/package/keypair). It's working fine for keys with small sizes but when I generate keys with 2048 in size, it's taking so long to perform it so I would like to use Open SSL directly from Node.js using Node's child_process as described in the script down below :

```
var cp = require('child_process')
  , assert = require('assert');

var privateKey, publicKey;
publicKey = '';
cp.exec('openssl genrsa 2048', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  assert.ok(!err);
  privateKey = stdout;
  console.log(privateKey);
  makepub = cp.spawn('openssl', ['rsa', '-pubout']);
  makepub.on('exit', function(code) {
    assert.equal(code, 0); 
    console.log(publicKey);
  });
  makepub.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    publicKey += data;
  });
  makepub.stdout.setEncoding('ascii');
  makepub.stdin.write(privateKey);
  makepub.stdin.end();  
});
```

This is working and more faster in key pairs generation than the Node.js keypair module so the issue I'm having is that I don't understand this code (if it's writing files on the server side and reading keys from them or not?) and I would like to turn this script into a function that returns a JSON or an array as result that holds the public and private key.

So any suggestion is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: node.js is not a language. just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..  Moved the code around a little.  Uses tmp file, which is deleted, possibly could be done without the tmp file, but this should work.

```
var cp = require('child_process')
  , assert = require('assert')
  , fs = require('fs')
  ;

// gen pub priv key pair
function genKeys(cb){
    // gen private
    cp.exec('openssl genrsa 2048', function(err, priv, stderr) {
      // tmp file
      var randomfn = './' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      fs.writeFileSync(randomfn, priv);
      // gen public
      cp.exec('openssl rsa -in '+randomfn+' -pubout', function(err, pub, stderr) {
           // delete tmp file
           fs.unlinkSync(randomfn);
           // callback
           cb(JSON.stringify({public: pub, private: priv}, null, 4));
      });

    });
}

genKeys(console.log);
```

Comment: Working Awesome, Thank you so much. Just for my curiosity what did you mean by "possibly could be done without the tmp file" ?

Comment: Pipe the private key directly to the second command, eliminating the need to write a temp file to disk.  Didn't see how to do that however.

Answer (score 0):

### You can simply use the small [rsa-json](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rsa-json) module

It's really **easy to use** and it's **asynchronous**:

```
var createRsaKeys = require('rsa-json');

createRsaKeys({bits: 1024}, function(err, keyPair) {
    console.log(keyPair.private);
    console.log(keyPair.public);
});
```

[rsa-json](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rsa-json) does not make a direct uses of [OpenSSL RSA_generate_key](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html) but uses [ssh-keygen](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1) (from [OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)) which is a wrapper around OpenSSL. There is no direct security difference (see [this for more information](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29876/what-are-the-differences-between-ssh-generated-keysssh-keygen-and-openssl-keys)).

PS: Have a look at the only [48 lines of code](https://github.com/substack/rsa-json/blob/master/index.js) composing rsa-json.

---

If you **really** want to use OpenSSL, you can have a look at the [ursa module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ursa) but:

- It's **not asynchronous**
- Is not maintained, the [last commit](https://github.com/Medium/ursa/commit/3d58df91226e5c26c8a3178e0cb4e289600e4b0d) was from Dec 21, 2012
- The project is heavy, it does too much things like sugary stuff (base64 encoding, etc.).
- It's have  embedded C++ OpenSSL wrapper inside it, initialized during installation.

---

PS: [keypair](https://www.npmjs.org/package/keypair) uses native JS, that's why it's very slow. It's not recommended with Node.js which is not good at performing CPU-intensive operations (but good with non-blocking events).